Fantasy book series that begins with mages arriving at a small village and taking a young woman against her will to be trained
Trying to remember fantasy series that begins with mages arriving at a small village and taking a young woman against her will to be trained. She is reluctantly accompanied by her male friend who is a beer maker. I remember wolf-like creatures killing people. A mage college where the evil head mage was killed. At the end of one of the books, the heroes escape by boat to the sea while a mage is destroying the port. I believe the heroine is related to royalty. I remember a battle in a village where a mage cast a spell and made one of the monsters into a giant.

In roughly which year/s did you read this?

This sounds like the Benjamin Ashwood series by A. C. Cobble. Ben wants to be a brewer and Amelie is the reluctant mage.

Yes, though the girl that the mage takes is Meghan, and her friend is Ben. Amelie is the mage who visits the village and takes Meghan.
